Powershell 7 property with dashes or hyphens in its name
I have some properties with hyphens in their names.
In powershell 5 I can get the value of the property with $variable.'property-name'.
However this is not working in powershell 7.
for example:
$response.Headers

Key                       Value
---                       -----
Connection                keep-alive
Request-Context           appId=cid-v1:e7e5e5c5-14a3-41a0-8724-6a5090e83fe5
Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains
Content-Length            0
Date                      Fri, 07 Jun 2024 14:37:22 GMT
Location                  https://auth.barracudanetworks.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=j1Skduh5hOyyW7OqlPe8qSKwLukh...
Set-Cookie                .AspNetCore.Correlation.YzsM7RBu_2pvg6AJyrCDQ4gwSglsRPz6rIi9EL1Siu0=N; expires=Fri, 07 Jun...

In powershell 5 I can get $response.Headers.'Set-Cookie'
.AspNetCore.Correlation.YzsM7RBu_2pvg6AJyrCDQ4gwSglsRPz6rIi9EL1Siu0=N; expires=Fri, 07 Jun 2024 14:52:22 GMT; path=/signin-oidc; secure; samesite=none; httponly

In powershell 7 $response.Headers.'Set-Cookie' is blank.
But $response.Headers shows me the same output as powershell 5, as seen above. And I can clearly see there is a 'Set-Cooklie' property.
The same goes for 'Request-Context' etc etc.
Non-hyphenated properties like $response.Headers.Date or $response.Headers.Location display just fine.
How do I get hyphenated properties in Powershell 7

im not able to replicate in either pwsh version, $response = Invoke-WebRequest 'google.com'; $response.Headers.'Set-Cookie' works fine in both. what if you try with $response.Headers['Set-Cookie'] ?

This works on my Windows 10, PowerShell 7.4.2 system.

$response.Headers.value[3] works

is $response.Headers.GetType() a Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> ?

$response.Headers.GetType()
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType

True     False    HttpResponseHeaders                      System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpHeaders

I'm moving on ... I got the value I was looking and went on to the next step and what I was trying to do .. doesnt work anyway.
I also did another test
$object = [pscustomobject]@{
'hyphenated-property' = 'This is a value'
'normalProperty'      = 'This is another value'
}
and $object.'hyphenated-property' works fine .. so hyphenated properties are actually fine.

Im not sure how you're getting that header type, are you using HttpWebRequest class manually? You should clarify how you're getting $response

$response Invoke-WebRequest  $janusUrl -SessionVariable janusSession -MaximumRedirection 0
